# How to WHERE query muliple rows with the same id as one in mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, where-clause

i'm stuck and trying to figure out how to do the right WHERE query.
This is the table:

```
post_id   property_id   property_value_id   property_value_custom   
77        2             3                   NULL
79        1             1                   NULL
79        2             2                   NULL
79        2             3                   NULL
79        4             NULL                111
80        3             4                   NULL
```

I want to select the post, WHERE `property_value_id = 3` AND `property_value_custom = "111"`.

The result should be post_id 79. How to query that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group by post_id` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select post_id
from tablename
group by post_id
having sum(property_value_id = 3) > 0 
   and sum(property_value_custom = 111) > 0
```

or:

```
having max(property_value_id = 3) = 1 
   and max(property_value_custom = 111) = 1
```